# Context in environment is not connected warning even if context is connected

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I move from a detail view of an object to its edit view , where I will edit the coredata object values, I keep getting  `Context in environment is not connected warning`

I have added the DataController in environment and also created a data class, can any one please suggest where is my issue

I keep getting this error in my @main struct

DataController class

```
@MainActor
class DataController: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = DataController()
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    @Published var carSheet: [CarDetails] = []
    @Published var logInfo = false
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CarData")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        
        container.loadPersistentStores { descriptions, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("failed to load data store \(error)")
            }
            

        }
    }
    
    func save() {
        if container.viewContext.hasChanges {
              try? container.viewContext.save()
        }
    }
    
    func delete(obj: NSManagedObject) {
        container.viewContext.delete(obj)
    }
    
    func getData() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<CarDetails>(entityName: "CarDetails")
       

        do {
             carSheet = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)

            
        } catch {
            print("Error getting data. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    
    func simpleSuccess() {
        let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
        generator.notificationOccurred(.success)
    }
}
```

my @main

```
@main
struct appDemo: App {  
    let userInfo = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "loginData")
    @StateObject var dataController =  DataController()

    var body: some Scene {

                WindowGroup {
                    if userInfo {
                        NavigationStack {
                            ContentView(dataContent: dataController)
                            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)                        }
        
                    } else {
        
                        LogInView( dataLog: dataController)
        
                    }
                }
        
    }
}
```

my Edit View which gives error when I fetch the data

```
struct EditViewData: View {
    @FetchRequest(entity: CarDetails.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var myCars: FetchedResults<CarDetails>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
           
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc` in your view.

Comment: In EditViewData I added it , but still the warnings remains, if I remove the @FetchRequest all warnings go , thanks

Comment: Then there isn’t enough information here to help you

Comment: You are correct , what happened was , I was using a login and logout page and jumping to ContentView() from there as well , this lead to unavailibity of Context,i added the  .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataLog.container.viewContext)  at all such places and now the code works fine, thanks and really appreciate the help

Comment: Great that you resolved this issue!

Comment: You should also move the injection onto the navigation stack/one line down/other side of the curly bracket.

Comment: NavigationStack {
                            ContentView(dataContent: dataController)
                                             }  .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)         like this ? thanks